# Results of for loop not adding to variable

Tags: python-2.7, count

So i made the following code to calculate my overal adverage mark:

```
def report_card(GPA):
    total = 0

    for courses, marks in GPA:
        print courses,'-',marks

    for courses, marks in GPA:
        total = total =+ marks
        print total / len(GPA)




report_card([('History', 84), ('Physics', 76), ('English', 91), ('Science', 64)])
```

I thouht since I want total to be total += marks it would count count up all the marks of the subject i follow up together, but this is not happening, it prints the marks one-by-one and divide this one mark by 4 (the length of GPA)

So how do i make my marks be counted up as one number

Comment: Replace `total = total =+ marks` with `total += marks`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is either:

```
total = total + marks
```

or:

```
total += marks
```

What you wrote is parsed as if you'd written:

```
total = total = (+marks)
```

`+marks` is equivalent to just `marks`, so it's equivalent to:

```
total = total = marks
```

which is equivalent to:

```
total = marks
```